# How to print numbers in a list that are less than a variable. Python

Tags: python

```
import random

Random_num=random.randint(0,10)

if Random_num == 1 or Random_num == 2 or Random_num == 3 or Random_num == 4 or Random_num == 5 or Random_num == 6 or Random_num == 7 or Random_num == 8 or Random_num == 9 or Random_num == 10:
    l.append(Random_num)

print(l)

print(Random_num)
```

I want to make the Random number that I generate between 1 and 10 recognize that it is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 put all the numbers less than it in a list.

Like if the Random Number is 7 then I want to put all the numbers less than it in a list.

*I am a beginner.* 
*Also I am specifically on Python 3.7*

Comment: Did you try an if statement which is single condition like, if (Random_num < some_variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
random_num=random.randint(0,10)
list = []
list.extend(range(random_num))
```

This should do the trick.

```
range(random_num)
```

is an iterator of all numbers smaller than random_num.

```
list(range(random_num))
```

is a list of all numbers smaller than random_num.

You can use the extend method to impart 'list' with the elements of the iterator.

Comment: But @Horba's solution is the most fundamental imo

Answer (score 2):

1) you create your number the way you did.
2) you do `my_list = range(random_num)` which creates a list from 0 until your random_num -1

for example, if random_num = 7,
list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

Answer (score 2):

```
import random
n = random.randint(0,10)
i = 1
l = []
while i < n:
    l.append(i)
    i = i + 1
print(l)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not that clear but here is what you want:

```
import random
n=random.randint(0,10)
l=list(range(n))
print(l)
```

Comment: to be fair he said he wanted to put the numbers in a list, not make a list with the numbers in it

Comment: U9-Forward is completely correct. I thought I'd add a procedural solution as this is for a beginner.

Answer (score -1):

```
import random
random_num=random.randint(0,10)
your_nums = list(range(10))
wanted_nums = []
for your_num in your_nums:
    if your_num < random_num:
        wanted_nums.append(your_num)
print(wanted_nums)
```

not sure if above codes meet your need.there may be a better one.but this is all i know yet